# Print out the list of grades along with P or F at the end

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is the code I have so far. The end result needs to ask user for the input scores and the loop continues until -99 is entered which will then print out the scores along with "P" or "F" under it. Can anyone help me to do that?

```
scores = []

def print_scores(copy_scores):
    for score in copy_scores[:-1:]:
       print(copy_scores[-1])

def find_min_odd(scores_list):
   return min(scores_list)

def set_grades(scores_list):
   grades = []
for score in scores_list:
   if score >= 50:
      grades.append('P')
   elif score < 50:
        grades.append('F')

for grade in grades:
  print('{:>2}'.format(grade)) 
while True:
   user_input = raw_input ("Please enter your score value: ")
   for score_value in user_input.split():
     if score_value == -99:
        break

scores.append(int(score_value))
  print_scores(scores)
  set_grades(scores)

print('minimum score:', find_min_odd(scores))
```

Comment: What part specifically are you having problems with? This is far too broad.

Comment: Trying to print out the grades and P or F at the end. Example output needs  50 90 80                                                                                                         F   P   P

Comment: And what's your question? You appear to have code that tries to achieve that. Are you getting an error? Are the results you're getting wrong? You need to actually give details about what the problem is.

Comment: It does not terminate after I put in -99 and does not print in the expected output format.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your while loop. Change your while loop like below and I hope the following code will give what you want

```
def find_min_odd(scores_list):
    return min(scores_list)

grades = []
def set_grades(scores_list):
    for score in scores_list:
        if score >= 50:
            grades.append([score,'P'])
        elif score < 50:
            grades.append([score,'F'])
    return grades

user_input = 0 

scores_list = []

while int(user_input) != -99:
    user_input = input('Please enter your score value')
    if int(user_input) != -99:
        scores_list.append(int(user_input))

for grade in set_grades(scores_list):
    print("Score: " + str(grade[0]), "Result:" + grade[1])

print('minimum score:', find_min_odd(scores_list))
```

Output:

```
Please enter your score value 20
Please enter your score value 50
Please enter your score value 70
Please enter your score value -99
Score: 20 Result:F
Score: 50 Result:P
Score: 70 Result:P
minimum score: 20
```

Comment: thankyou so much. The output at the end needs to be printed as a list with the new line showing whether its a pass or F do you have any idea how to do that?Also the odd minimum number needs to be displayed